# What does comparing types do in Python 2?

Tags: python-2.x

Consider this code:

```
class class1:
    pass

class class2:
    pass

class1 > class2
```

In Python 3, I (rightly) receive this error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type'
```

What happens in Python 2?

```
>>> class1 > class2
False
>>> class2 > class1
True
>>>
```

Comment: Posting this because the answer was not easily googleable.

Comment: That answer is for Python 3.

Comment: Okay, so I installed python 2 and you're wrong. The comparison operator is defined. I'm still not sure what it does.

Comment: Yes, this is odd Python 2 behavior that makes no reasonable sense.

Comment: So does it raise the error or not? The question asserts it does. The comment asserts it does not. Now the question asserts it does *and* does not.. it's one or the other or there is an environmental difference. Please include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), possible with an Online Example.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it raises an error on Python 3.

Comment: So then we are back to the start.. RTFM for the *specific version*. Also, check the tags and clarify environments better in questions.

Comment: Python 3 explicitly *requires* a well-defined ordering for comparisons:  https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html - **"The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number, the objects are of different types that cannot be compared, or *other cases where there is no defined ordering.*"** The Python 2 documentation is less strict, saying **"The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number."** There was indeed a semantic change.

Comment: Thus, in Python 3, `type > type` *must* throw a TypeError in to conform to the Standard Type model; arguably an ordering *could* be defined, but.. furthermore, from Python 2: **"CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; *objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address*."**

Comment: Yes, I know how Python 3 works. I don't know how Python 2 works because I don't use it.

Comment: Do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user2864740 said in a comment:

In Python 3, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html),

> The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number, the objects are of different types that cannot be compared, or *other cases where there is no defined ordering.*

In Python 2,

> The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.
>   CPython implementation detail: *Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.*

Because classes are all the same type (`types.ClassType`), `class1 < class2` will depend on what the memory addresses of the two class objects happen to be.

Comment: `class1` and `class2` are objects of the same type, that type being `types.ClassType`.

Comment: @Blckknght: Yeah, I realized that and edited my comment.

Comment: [Here's an example run](https://ideone.com/yevDMB) where `class1 > class2` because the addresses happen to be ordered differently.

Comment: @user2357112: Sorry for the mistake! I've edited my answer.